# Pandas: Filter out the rows (unique ID) that contains two desirable values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like below;

```
ID          code

333_c_132   x
333_c_132   n06
333_c_132   n36
333_c_132   n60
999_c_133   x
999_c_133   n06
999_c_133   n12
999_c_133   n24
998_c_134   x
998_c_134   n06
998_c_134   n12
998_c_134   n18
998_c_134   n36
997_c_135   x
997_c_135   n06
997_c_135   n12
997_c_135   n24
997_c_135   n36
```

I want to filter out the rows (unique ID) that contains both `x` and `n36`. ie

```
ID          code
333_c_132   x
333_c_132   n36
998_c_134   x
998_c_134   n36
997_c_135   x
997_c_135   n36
```

I tried like this bellow;

```
df = df[(df.code == "x") | (df.code == "n36")]
```

but it returns `999_c_133   x` as well.. which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use, [`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) to create a boolean mask `m1` & `m2` then use `groupby` to group the mask `m1` & `m2` on `df[ID]`, now use `transform(any)` to create a boolean mask which satisfy the codition where the `ID` contains both the values `m1` and `m2`, thereafter filter the dataframe using this mask:

```
m1 = df['code'].eq('x')
m2 = df['code'].eq('n36')
m = (
    m1.groupby(df['ID']).transform('any') & 
    m2.groupby(df['ID']).transform('any') & 
    df['code'].isin(['x', 'n36'])
)
df1 = df[m]
```

---

```
# print(df1)
           ID code
0   333_c_132    x
2   333_c_132  n36
8   998_c_134    x
12  998_c_134  n36
13  997_c_135    x
17  997_c_135  n36
```

Comment: could you please suggest any resources where I can learn these stuff? I have very informal knowledge about the pandas dataframe. thank you.

Comment: I suggest you to learn from the official pandas docs, for example a great resource would be [this official pandas guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide). Apart from this a great resource on using `groupby, transform, apply` would be [pandas groupby guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html). But the only way to get the grasp on the concepts is by actually applying those learned concepts on the actual data itself.